# Is it possible to associate records N-N multiple times via different name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, orm, mongoid

I'm using Mongoid.

If a task has a list of writers, then a task `has_many :writers` and a writer `has_many :tasks`.

What if I want a task to `has_many :editors` as well, but the have the `Writer` model to act as editor?

In other words, is there a way to relate the same model twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, please check the correctness yourself and adjust if needed

```
has_many :editors, class_name: "Writer", inverse_of: :writter
```

So you should use **inverse_of** and **class_name**